# Difference between m3ua as signaling and as application server

Tags: restcomm, ss7, signaling

I have studied that Restcomm jss7 stack can be deployed in three modes i.e. as an application server, as a signaling gateway and as an IPSP. I can understand that IPSP extends the signaling gateway functionality over IP. However i can't find good explanation of AS vs signaling gateway. Can anyone clarify with suitable example

Answer (score 0):

An AS, Application Server is the software that performing the telecom service you are using. In example, a SMSC is one standard Application Server, because is sending, receiving, storing SMS. Another well-know Application Server is voice-mail.
SG, Signaling Gateway, just converts Signal protocol from one protocol to another one. Old usual Signaling gateway was to convert E1/T1 to IP, but now, as, there are a lot IP Telecom protocol, you can convert from one to another.

As I know nothing about Restcomm, your question learn me for sure that on Restcomm, when you are building an application server with that Restcomm stack, you may easily open your application to different IP protocols because that product can act like Signaling Gateway. You are not lock to one protocol.